# Dynamically prevent page scrolling on pointerdown event

Tags: javascript, touch, internet-explorer-11, dom-events, pointer-events

I use canvas to paint objects that can be dragged around. 
If user touches an area with no objects, he can scroll the page.
I have a working touch events implementation and have trouble  adding PointerEvents API support.

With touch events API I use `event.preventDefault()` to prevent the scrolling.

Now with PointerEvents API it does not work - I get the `pointerDown` event but no move events and automatic page scrolling kicks in.

So far I have found that you can use the `touch-action` CSS property to switch between page scrolling and touch actions, but not a way to do it on per-touch basis.

For example a user might scroll the page with one finger and simultaneously move an object with second finger.